# no uncaughtException in console or logs when attempting to use an undefined variable on asynchronous promise chain on nodejs

Tags: node.js, logging, promise, q

I noticed something really weird:

On an asynchronous promise chain, when I mistakenly try to log a non existing variable, it created an exception that I could not see in console.

When I call the exact same function in a synchronous manner (called it directly from the method with out activating it asynchronously as a result of a resolved promise chain) it showed the expected error (see exception with stack trace below).

This drove me nuts, because the promise chain activated the method (I can see it started to do things by a log line I added at its beginning), but then it reaches the problematic log line which stopped the entire method from fulfilling its goal, yet no error was printed and no stack trace was seen.

This makes the entire debugging issue pretty complicated, and I'm sure I'm doing something wrong here. But what is it?

This is the code I used: (I marked the badly written variable)

```
module.exports = {
  sync: function(){
      console.log(doesNotExist); // error logs
  }, 
  async: function(){
      Q().then(function(){ // actually from an API returning a promise
        console.log(doesNotExist); // no error in log or `unhandledException` process event
      });
  }
};
```

UPDATE:
after utilizing benjamin's solution

```
process.on("unhandledRejection", function(r, e){
console.log("Oh No! Unhandled rejection!! \nr::", r,"\ne::", e);
});
```

things got much better. now i get some log printing that looks like this

```
Oh No! Unhandled rejection!!
r:: [ReferenceError: Resolved123PasswordHash is not defined]
e:: { state: 'rejected',reason: [ReferenceError: Resolved123PasswordHash is not defined] }
```

but still i get no actual stacktrace like in synchronous  method call.

this is how it looks like when i call the method directly with no promise chain:

```
2015-07-05T18:22:51.405Z :: [ error ] :: uncaughtException: Resolved123PasswordHash is not defined["ReferenceError: Resolved123PasswordHash is not defined",
"    at addUserAfterHashResolved (I:\\iBitch\\services\\userServices.js:19:77)",
"    at Object.module.exports.addUser (I:\\iBitch\\services\\userServices.js:22:3)",
"    at Object.<anonymous> (I:\\iBitch\\ikuter.js:263:14)",
"    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)",
"    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)",
"    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)",
"    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)",
"    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)",
"    at startup (node.js:129:16)",
"    at node.js:814:3"]
```

is it possible to get a full stacktrace even when using async promise?

because the error message is nice, but it still doesn't direct me to specific code line so i can know what i should fix.

YET ANOTHER EDIT::
i found out that if i use ".done()" at the end of the promise chain, it will show stacktrace, but then it will crash the entire application (which is also undesired behavior)
maybe thats the direction i need to take, but modify it a bit?
i understood that if i'll start putting each promise chain under try/catch it will severely impact performance, so obviously not the complementing solution here...

anyway, any further help will be appriciated.

Comment: What's wrong with my solution? You don't need `.done`....

Comment: If you want stack traces log `r.stack`, if you want long stack traces do `Q.longStackTraces = true`, chances are you want to use bluebird in favor of Q here anyway.

Comment: i set longStackTraces=true yesterday, it didn't cause the stacktrace to be presented when i printed r to logs. maybe i need to specifically print "r.stack" like you said now and not just "r".

Comment: and i totally agree with you regarding bluebird.... read about it a bit and everyone advise to use it as the promise library of choice (much like you). its more of a mental state. i already had to learn so much to start using javascript nodejs and then promises. and now after everything works (sorta...) i just can't find the mental resources to switch to bluebird and start figuring out why everything broke again. but i will do the switch! i "promise" i will..... heheh

Comment: addition of r.stack to the log worked perfectly well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using Q 1.3+ you're looking for `unhandledRejection` and not `uncaughtException`:

```
process.on("unhandledRejection", function(r, e){
    console.log("Oh No! Unhandled rejection!!", r, e);
});
```

Before 1.3 this functionality didn't exist in Q. Other libraries like bluebird have this built in for years now.

The reason promises behave this way is that you still might attach a `.catch` handler in the future which would let you handle errors. The process event assumes that if you haven't attached a `.catch` in an event loop turn you never will (reasonable IMO).

Comment: the solution worked well. (with the additional printing of r.stack as you described in the comments to the question)